# Legally extract oil

Tags: property, mineral-rights

Supposedly I purchased a land and I found that beneath this land there is a huge amount of oil. Now is it legal if I extract this oil and sell it or does this oil belongs to the country?

Comment: A country tag would be helpful.

Comment: The law on this differs a great deal from country to country. In some countries mineral rights belong to the country, in some they belong to the property owner, and in some countries (like the U.S.) there is a hybrid system depending on the exact means by which the property was acquired from the sovereign. So, a country code is necessary to know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The oil belongs to whoever owns the mineral rights over the land - normal freehold does not include ownership of minerals such as oil.

Comment: I would say that fee simple ownership generally includes mineral rights unless they have been expressly reserved by deed or a relevant statute or national constitution says otherwise.

Comment: In Australia mineral leases are in the gift of each state and are divorced from freehold title

Comment: But, I suspect that there is a severance of the minerals in the patent from the Australian government at the root of title.

Comment: @ohwilleke state government law, but yes.